# how to get the link of hyperlinkfield in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

so i have a grid view like this :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="VideoID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="VideoID" HeaderText="VideoID" ReadOnly="True" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="VideoID" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="VideoEpisodeNumber" HeaderText="Episode" SortExpression="VideoEpisodeNumber"></asp:BoundField>
       <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="VideoUrl" HeaderText="Video Url" DataTextFormatString="Link"/>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="VideoDescription" HeaderText="VideoDescription" SortExpression="VideoDescription"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

the hyperlinkfield is supposed to have the video links! how can i retrieve that link when a user click on it? 
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="VideoUrl" HeaderText="Video Url" DataTextFormatString="Link" onclick="javascript:GetURL(this);"/>


function GetURL(sender) {
//Possibly sender should contain the object.
//if not
                var parent = $find(sender.id);
var linkURL = parent.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: HyperLinkField does not have a Onclick property!

Comment: Why don't you use a Template field instead? with a link button inside it? @alinem .Also have you tried adding the onclick property, (usually the rendered html allows onclick, so you can add it, regardless of the intellisense not showing it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are propagating DataNavigationUrlFields the href attribute will be set. Then you should be able to intercept the navigation to the corresponding video url (assuming that resolving the url on the client is what you are looking for)

**Gridview**

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="VideoUrl" HeaderText="Video Url" NavigateUrl="http://wwww.youtube.com" />
```

**Javascript (jquery)**

```
$(function () {
    $("#myGridviewId a").on("click", interceptNavigation);
});

function interceptNavigation() {
    alert($(this).attr("href"));
}
```

Comment: well...it works on any anchor tag except the "Link" tags which which are in the gridview1. when i click on it, it redirects me to the link instead of interceptNavigation and displaying alert box. any idea why is that happening?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a navigation field where the interception does not work? I updated my answer with a HyperLinkField Tag which works with my solution.